# Finding a prorcess by name,indicating to user that the process run,then killing the process

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, msgbox

I want to make a simple update application in vb.net,but,it cant update the file,cause the file is running.So,i want to find all processes called "seemta helper(this is how Task m. show it's name)"and,if,a process is running with that name,indicating to the user with a msgbox that the process is running,and,when the user press the OK button,then killing the process.

P.S. Sorry for bad english. :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Your question is a little too broad as it asks for a complete solution and not only a _single_ problem. Start with [`Process.GetProcessesByName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) and come back if you have a _specific_ problem implementing your solution.

Comment: Yea,i have,i dont know how to use Process.GetProcessByName,in an IF statement.so this is where i stuck currently.

Comment: So,if a process is running with the name "seemta helper"then it need to be indicated to user,and,when the user press the OK button in the msgbox,then killing the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("seemta helper")
    If MessageBox.Show("Kill " + p.ProcessName + "(" + p.Id + ")?", "Kill", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
        p.Kill()
    End If
Next
```

[`GetProcessesByName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an array of running `Process` instances with the specified name.

Then you show a message box to ask the user if the process should be killed and if <kbd>Yes</kbd> is clicked, you call `Kill()` on that process's instance.

Comment: Just a question,how can i implement code like you did?

Comment: @Ntohing_Trolll Sorry, I don't understand that question. You mean, how to copy and paste? It sounds like you rather need some basic vb tutorials before asking on SO.

Comment: It throw's me an erorr: Conversion from string "Kill" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: No,i mean,how can i paste the code like you,i know how to paste,and copy :D

Comment: You mean the formating on StackOverlow? Simply add four spaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: `It work :D` Thumbs up for you :D Thanks for your help ;D

Comment: Yes, that's for inline code formating. But for code blocks you add 4 spaces at the beginning of the line (google for markdown syntax).

Comment: I will,thanks a lot,but,just a question,what if multiple processes are running with the same name?

Comment: The code I show opens a message box _for each_ process found with that name (and kills it if yes is clicked). You may consider to ask only once and kill all or add a cancel button and break the loop if the user wants to cancel.

Comment: Just a question,what if there are no process with that name?The msgbox will not open?

Comment: Correct, since the _For Each_ loop is not entered if there's no element in the returned array.

Comment: I got a little problem,and the probelm is:I want to use your code,to stop the user,to start multiple times the application,but,the application wont start because,it detects itself as the application.

Comment: So,i need some source of code,stop the user to open the application multiple times called "seemta helper".

Comment: @Ntohing_Trolll This is a completely different topic and you should ask a new question for that. But please use google first as there are a lot of resources about that on the web. And note that SO is not a free coding service, you'll have to show at least some research effort and the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim Processes() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("seemta helper")

For Each process As Process In Processes
     process.Kill()
Next
```

You may need administrator elevation to kill a process